# MODX Revolution: How to stop temporarily?

Tags: web-development-server, modx-revolution

In our project, we are migrating our website from MODX platform to React framework. In-order to test the new website, I would like to temporarily disable MODX platform from publishing the website. I tried to look for such a procedure, but to no avail. Can anyone explain how to do this?

Note: Web development is not my expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please pay attention to next MODX system settings, they help you with disable your website: `site_status`, `site_unavailable_message` and `site_unavailable_page`

[image]